# How do I set a default value of 0 to a radtextbox in a radgrid if the value is null after databind?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid, radtextbox

i have a series of radtextboxes as columns in a radgrid.  The data they pull is often null.  I'd like them to have a default value of zero in those cases.  How do i accomplish this?

I tried this without success:

```
    protected void rGrid_Inductions_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridDataItem item in rGrid_Inductions.Items)
        {
            foreach (Control ctr in item.Controls)
            {
                if (ctr.GetType() == typeof(RadTextBox))
                {
                    (ctr as RadTextBox).Text = "0" + (ctr as RadTextBox).Text;
                }
            }                
        }  

        rGrid_Inductions.Rebind();
    }
```

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont u just set the Default Text of RadTextBox=0 when you creating them and then in this (prerender loop) modify them if they are not null;

Comment: this sounds like what i need, but how do i accomplish that in the prerender loop?  would you have a link or sample code, by chance?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely set the Default value when you drop the control on the page if you are creating the Control on Design View or on code behind http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-textbox-basics.html

Im puzzled as to why do you concatenate the text with the

```
(ctr as RadTextBox).Text = "0" + (ctr as RadTextBox).Text;
```

Is the 0 supposed to be permanent regardless of the text? Can you show me a sample Text?

However if all you want is the 0 as default, all you have to do is assign the value on design time or code behind like in the documentation that I posted above.